# Keep the scope in Async.js

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, async.js

Given the following class in Coffeescript:

```
class MyClass extends events.EventEmitter

    someObj: null # set somewhere during constructor

    someMethod: () ->
        async.parallel([
            @task1,
            @task2,
            @task3,
        ], (err, results) ->
            doSomething()

    task1: (callback) ->
            @someObj.funnyMethod()   # fails
            callback()
);
```

The call for `@someObj.funnyMethod()` on the second last line fails:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'funnyMethod' of undefined`

Obviously, `this` refers to the context inside the callback. For normal callbacks, I've learned we would use the fat arrow operator `=>` instead of the thin one `->`.

What's a clean way to handle this with async.js (or any other similar library)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fat arrow in the definition of `task1`:

```
task1: (callback) =>
```

However, I wouldn't recommend it.  A fat arrow for methods is quite different from a fat arrow for functions, and has performance penalties.

What you probably want is to pass bound versions of those functions to `async.parallel`.  You can either do this with `Function::bind`, or with anonymous fat-arrow functions:

```
@task1.bind(@), # Function::bind
=> @task2(),    # anonymous function
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Well now I have a different problem. I'm going to change my question.

Comment: @Atmocreations That's not a comment, its an answer.  Please create a new question instead of changing old ones.  Editing is for adding details and correcting minor mistakes, not for completely changing the question.

Comment: I know, sorry. I actually meant to write "contribution". I thought it was okay to modify the question. It actually relates to what you wrote and it's a direct follow-up to your reply. And for a comment, my code snippet seemed too large to me.

Comment: @Atmocreations If you have a new problem, open a new question.  This will work better for you, since newer questions are more visible.

Comment: kay, done that - thank you. For anyone who is interested in the other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164227/q-all-doesnt-call-tasks/27165386?noredirect=1#comment42831647_27165386