# Q.all doesn't call tasks

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, q

So I have this CoffeeScript (simplified to focus on the real problem)

```
Q = require 'q'
events = require 'events'

class SomeObj extends events.EventEmitter

  constructor: () ->
    setTimeout () =>
      @emit 'done'
    , 3000


class SomeObj2 extends events.EventEmitter

  constructor: () ->
    setTimeout () =>
      @emit 'done'
    , 50000

class Main

  someObj1: null
  someObj2: null
  constructor: () ->
    Q.all([
      => @task1(),
      => @task2()])
    .then (results)->
      console.log 'results'
      console.log results
    .catch((error)->
      console.log 'error'
      console.log error
    )

  task1: () ->
    console.log 'task1 started'
    defer = Q.defer()
    @someObj = new SomeObj()

    @someObj.on 'done', (err, data) =>
      console.log 'task1 done'
      defer.resolve data

    return defer.promise

  task2: () ->
    console.log 'task2 started'
    defer = Q.defer()
    @someObj2 = new SomeObj2()

    @someObj2.on 'done', (err, data) =>
      console.log 'task2 done'
      defer.resolve data

    return defer.promise


main = new Main()
```

The output is:

```
results
[ [Function], [Function] ]
```

In `Main::constructor`, the callbacks `@task1` and `@task2` doesn't seem to get called. So to be sure about this, I've had added `console.log` at the top of both of them. And as they don't get printed out, I can be sure they're not called.

For testing purposes, I replaced this block

```
  constructor: () ->
    Q.all([
      => @task1(),
      => @task2()])
    .then (results)->
      console.log 'results'
      console.log results
    .catch((error)->
      console.log 'error'
      console.log error
    )
```

by this block

```
  constructor: () ->
    Q.fcall () => @task1()
    .then ()  => @task2()
    .then (results)->
      console.log 'results'
      console.log results
    .catch((error)->
      console.log 'error'
      console.log error
    )
```

and this actually works as espected, but it's not what I want. The goal is to start task1 and 2 in parallel.

Side note: Inside the tasks, I would like to be able to use `@` for member variables of `Main`

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Q.all` helper](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#combination) expects an array or promises to resolve, not an array of functions. It means that you should call all your tasks yourself if you want to use `Q.all`.

In your example, removing anonymous function wrappings will do the trick:

```
constructor: () ->
  Q.all([
    @task1()
    @task2()
  ]).then (results) ->
    // Success
  .catch (error) ->
    // Error
```

Comment: Ah easy as that. I should've get to this myself, thank you! One little side-question on this: Why does this work with the scope in @task1 and @task2? In fact, it's good that in those functions I can use @-style calls. But why is the context correctly bound, even without the fat arrow?

Comment: @Atmocreations Because you're executing them synchronously in the context of your `constructor`, passing resulting promises to `Q.all`.